# Append result of SQL queries inside Excel cell

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I wrote a Excel macro that executes SQL queries and inserts the returned values in specific cells.
Each query returns a single string of text that occupies a part of a cell.

I accoplished that with:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

With this I can present results in the following way:

Cell A1:
String from query 1

Cell B1:
word "to"

Cell C1:
String from query 2

But I want to insert in the same cell, results of more than one query, appending the result of the second query after the first one in the following way:

Cell A1:
"String 1" to "String 2"

Someone can point me in the right direction?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string variable within your procedure that could hold that information. You would first add the specific field, then concatenate the 'to' to it then the second result like so:

```
Dim strResult As String

'Put your first connection / recordset call here'

strResult = rs.fields(0) & " to "

'Put your second connection / recordset call here'

strResult = strResult & rs.fields(0)
```

Comment: That did the trick perfectly. Thanks! I have a related question but I think is better to do it separately.